# How flutter parses ArrayBuffer

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, arraybuffer

flutter 2.0.0 uses the long connection websocket protocol, the returned data is ArrayBuffer, how to convert it into json data

[31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 144, 49, 79, 195, 48, 16, 70, 255, 10, 186, 217, 61, 249, 206, 103, 59, 241, 214, 38, 65, 68, 13, 36, 212, 41, 66, 221, 2, 237, 192, 208, 5, 194, 84, 229, 191, 115, 41, 147, 101, 125, 239, 61, 75, 190, 193, 231, 245, 12, 9, 126, 126, 63, 240, 123, 154, 47, 96, 224, 60, 205, 19, 164, 27, 28, 115, 61, 174, 231, 208, 119, 25, 146, 160, 48, 137, 129, 93, 126, 131, 196, 145, 48, 82, 136, 6, 218, 62, 43, 100, 209, 122, 239, 165, 208, 185, 122, 130, 20, 98, 68, 9, 6, 170, 237, 190, 81, 216, 161, 13, 106, 62, 182, 29, 36, 138, 1, 197, 137, 154, 117, 175, 162, 88, 100, 17, 29, 235, 109, 86, 145, 11, 198, 82, 43, 221, 160, 155, 35, 36, 13, 254, 231, 169, 8, 108, 160, 25, 43, 133, 244, 42, 209, 25, 120, 63, 12, 26, 68, 231, 136, 244, 177, 174, 125, 217, 171, 196, 120, 175, 159, 154, 149, 36, 143, 190, 92, 27, 207, 107, 132, 138, 184, 114, 247, 134, 148, 24, 189, 129, 215, 241, 168, 19, 9, 150, 236, 138, 101, 49, 48, 127, 93, 47, 250, 29, 108, 153, 54, 86, 54, 68, 15, 76, 73, 202, 100, 9, 150, 63, 238, 197, 136, 230, 44, 1, 0, 0]

Comment: if your list is a valid response from WS service then you should use `utf8.decode`

Comment: What charset is this suppose to be?